# How to synchronize the time with java calendar

Tags: java, calendar

How can i synchronize the time (second , hour).
i have this

```
  int minuto = cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
  int day_Completed = 1440;
```

but i have no idea how can i do it.

I tried doing this

changing the pc time when a loop is running to see if the var minuto change.
but doesn't work.

Comment: Perhaps it's a language barrier issue, but I'm really having a hard time figuring out what you're looking to do!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An instance of calendar statically reflects *one* moment in time. It won't get updated automatically, it is not behaving like a clock.

If you want to "synchronize" with the actual time, then you have to

1. use some sort of timer, maybe based on `Thread.sleep` for a start
2. on each "timer event" get the current time (`System.currentTimMillis()`) and
3. update the instance of calendar with that value.